# Prove $P(X\mid Y)= P(X\mid Y\cap E_i)P(E_i\mid Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning

Assume that $E_1,…,E_n$ are events that partition the sample space $S$. Let X and Y be events in $S$ such that $P(Y\cap E_i)>0$ $\forall 1\le i\le n$

I would like to show that

$$P(X\mid Y)= P(X\mid Y\cap E_i)P(E_i\mid Y)$$

How can I prove that?

Comment: Firstly, your title isn't descriptive of the problem (the information it gives is already given by the probability tag) - please edit this. Secondly, the statement as written is not true - there should be a summation over the $i$. Thirdly - are you familiar with the proof of the law of total probability, without any conditioning (i.e. $P(X) = \sum P(X|E_i) P(E_i)$)? If so, think about how this might change under conditioning over $Y$. If not, read this proof first, and then try to adapt it.

Comment: Sorry iI corrected my mistake in the question. Please look at this, does there any problem that you don’t understand? Btw, I will change its title. @stochasticboy321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X = E_1$, $Y = S$ and $E_2 = S \backslash E_1$.
Hence $P(X\mid Y)= 1$, $P(X\mid Y\cap E_2) = P(E_1 \mid E_2) =0$ and
$$P(X\mid Y)= 1 \ne 0 = P(X\mid Y\cap E_i)P(E_i\mid Y)$$ for $i=2$.

But $$P(X\mid Y)= \sum_{i=1}^n P(X\mid Y\cap E_i)P(E_i\mid Y)$$ as
$$P(X\mid Y) =  \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n P(X \cap Y\cap E_i)}{P(Y)}$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ P(X \cap Y\cap E_i)}{P(Y\cap E_i)} \frac{P(Y\cap E_i)}{P(Y)}
= \sum_{i=1}^n P(X\mid Y\cap E_i)P(E_i\mid Y)$$